# What is the recommended way to show a badge (a number) on the Application Icon?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, apple-push-notifications, android-notifications

I am creating a messaging mobile app using Xamarin. The app is expected to run on both Android and IOS. I need to implement notifications for this app in order to to show total number of unread messages over the application icon.

I am thinking of the following options:

1. Should I create a Background Service to do long pooling and call the
   server to get the total number of unread messages and show over the
   app icon?
2. Or create a Push Notification Service which pushes the total number of unread
   messages to the clients?

Please advise if there is any other recommended approach to accomplish this.

Thanks,

Arfan

Comment: You could refer to : https://github.com/alexrainman/badge

Answer (score 2):

iOS won't allow and encourage background services except in few scenarios like health kit data sync etc., So the clear option to go for this by push notifications. Please go with the second approach.

When you are sending a push notification data in JSON format like below, it will update:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Test Push Notification",
        "sound": "yourSound.aiff",
        "Badge": "desiredNumber"
    }
}
```

Comment: what about android?

Comment: In android, background services allowed. Still its recommended doing using push notifications only as u r already doing it in ios. so consistency will be there. just as an update: in latest version oreo background restrictions started

Comment: thanks. It'll be great if you could point me towards a sample, how to implement this for ios/android.

Comment: Please accept this answer in case it clarified your doubt. So that it will be useful to some other person having the same doubt as you.

Comment: "Badge": "desiredNumber" info solved a great mystery as to why my bagde number was reset to 0 every time I received a notification. I did not notice that in my code. thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Its called **Badges** for what you are taking about.

For your kind information, it is facility provided by **manufacturer** in Android,

**It may not show in many devices.**

Please [read article](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000013/?category=5245260) provided by WhatsApp

Comment: thanks for coming up with the terminology for this, but how should it be implemented?